# Why doesn't Rollup.js treeshake my library

Tags: typescript, rollupjs, tree-shaking

I have a utility library: [goodcore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/goodcore)
That I am using in another project. It works fine but when I use [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) to bundle and treeshake it, it always includes the whole goodcore library, even when I only use a very small portion of it that have no links what so ever to some of the included files.

Both projects are Typescript and use ES2015 module loading.

I reference the goodcore library using:

```
import { Arr, Pool, Range2, Timer, Util, Vec2 } from "goodcore";
```

and the index.js in goodcore looks like:

```
export { Vec2 as Vec2 } from "./struct/Vec2";
export { Range2 as Range2 } from "./struct/Range2";
export { Rect as Rect } from "./struct/Rect";
export { List as List } from "./struct/List";
export { Dictionary as Dictionary } from "./struct/Dictionary";
export { Stack as Stack } from "./struct/Stack";
export { Tree as Tree } from "./struct/Tree";
export { Calc as Calc } from "./Calc";
export { Dom as Dom } from "./Dom";
export { Arr as Arr } from "./Arr";
export { Obj as Obj } from "./Obj";
export { Util as Util } from "./Util";
export { Timer as Timer } from "./Timer";
export { Uri as Uri } from "./Uri";
export { Poolable as Poolable } from "./standard/mixins/Poolable";
export { Initable as Initable } from "./standard/mixins/Initable";
export { Pool as Pool } from "./standard/Pool";
export { Integrate as Integrate } from "./Integration";
export { MocData as MocData } from "./MocData";
export { Cache as Cache } from "./standard/Cache";
export { KeyValuePair as KeyValuePair } from "./struct/KeyValuePair";
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Still I end up with everything from goodcore, like the Tree, included in my rollup build of the other project, while I was under the impression that the treeshaking should remove things that were not used/referenced.

The rollup config for the other project looks like this:

```
var packageJson = require("./package.json");
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
export default {
    entry: 'src/lib/index.ts',
    targets: [
            { dest: 'dist/' + packageJson.name + '.umd.js', format: 'umd' },
            { dest: 'dist/' + packageJson.name + '.es.js', format: 'es' },
            { dest: 'dist/' + packageJson.name + '.iife.js', format: 'iife' }
    ],
    moduleName: packageJson.name,
    external: ['ts-md5/dist/md5'],
    sourceMap: true,
    globals: {
    },
    treeshake: true,
    plugins: [
        typescript({
            typescript: require('typescript')
        }),
        resolve({ module: true, jsnext: false, main: true, modulesOnly: true })
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure correctness, Rollup will include any code that looks like it might have side-effects — to give a trivial example, this bundle would cause 'hello from foo.js' to be logged even though `foo` isn't imported by `main.js`:

```js
/*--- main.js ---*/
import './foo.js';

/*--- foo.js  ---*/
export function unused () {
  // this will be omitted...
}

// but this will be included, because it has an effect on the world
console.log('hello from foo.js');
```

In the case of goodcore, *everything* looks to Rollup as though it might have side-effects. For example, `Calc` is the result of calling `_Calc()`, and since it's very hard to determine whether or not `_Calc()` has effects, it must be included regardless of whether or not `Calc` is used by the bundle. You can [see this in the REPL](https://rollupjs.org/repl?version=0.41.6&shareable=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).

Unfortunately, making this code treeshakeable would probably involve fairly substantial changes to the design. It's also possible that TypeScript is introducing non-treeshakeable constructs.

Comment: Oh Thanks! the _Calc thing I can remove since it was only to be able to use it as a factory when injecting in an iframe etc. After some testing I noticed that it is not only the _Calc but also the static properties on it. Meaning I have to remove both the asignment to Calc as well as all static functions. :( Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Yes — don't wrap the definition in an IIFE ([see gist](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/7861d982561a4d1457171ed783cde49c) — unfortunately SO won't let me link to the REPL directly). The trouble is that's code generated by TypeScript, which is what I was referring to by 'non-treeshakeable constructs'.

Comment: For future users. It can be solved by just strictly avoiding static properties or functions in any classes. If you need it as a sort of global variable than throw that state into a separate class which then always will be included but lets the rest be treeshakeable.